# php to count the remaining time frame

Tags: php, datetime

i am building a quiz system,

the fields on the table is:

**id, title, description, status, created, ended**

the logic goes this way:

a quiz last only one week, it will automatically ends on the last day of the week (i am thinking on Saturday 24:00), and the admin should input the quiz on any day of the week, if it is inputted on Wednesday say at 01:00 pm, then the system should count the remaining time frame (in this case it would be around 83 hours) and then adds it to current time() to be inserted to the "ended" field.

am i on the right track?? and if i am, how should i count the remaining time frame in PHP ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the time stamp using `strtotime();` and use the argument 'next saturday', so you could calculate the time remaining by doing something like this:

```
$timeRemaining = strtotime('next saturday') - time();
```

That will give you a timestamp in seconds which you can divide by 3600 to get the hours.

Comment: this one works, thanks man. Btw to get the hour, i should divide it by 3600 shouldn't i ?

Comment: Oh yeah, it's still early! Also as suggested below you may want to do 'next sunday' to get 00:00 on Sunday (1 second after 23:59:59 on Saturday).

Comment: yes i modified a bit of your code and changed it to 'next sunday' instead :D. i get the point though thanks man

Answer (score 2):

On PHP >= 5.3.0 you can use the function [date_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

On previous version you can use something like this

```
$date1 = time(); 
$date2 = mktime(0,0,0,01,28,2011);

$diff = $date2 - $date1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the ending time by using the [`mktime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) or [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function, and find the time remaining using

```
// Saturday, this week
$ends = strtotime('next saturday');
$remaining = $ends - time(); // Remaining time in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the question correctly, i.e. you want the end date to be stored in the db then Can this not just be achieved with

$ended = strtotime("+1 week");

Answer (score 0):

Note that 24:00 on Saturday doesn't exist. The time goes from 23:59:59 on Saturday to 00:00:00 on Sunday.

No need to add the times together manually. When the quiz is created you can use `$end_time = strtotime( 'next Sunday' );` to get the time for the quiz to end (00:00:00 on Sunday morning).